# Flume does not store data to hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, flume

While I'm able to store Flume data (from Kafka) in HDFS correctly, I have no luck getting them stored in HBase... The platform is Cloudera 5.10.1.

My flume conf is:

```
tier1.sources  = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
#tier1.sinks = hdfs1
tier1.sinks = hbase1

tier1.sources.source1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
tier1.sources.source1.zookeeperConnect = master3d.localdomain:2181
tier1.sources.source1.topics.regex = application.data.*
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.sources.source1.interceptors = i1
tier1.sources.source1.interceptors.i1.type = timestamp
tier1.sources.source1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms = 100
tier1.sources.source1.kafka.consumer.group.id = flume

tier1.channels.channel1.type = memory
tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000

tier1.sinks.hbase1.type = hbase
tier1.sinks.hbase1.table = application_data
tier1.sinks.hbase1.columnFamily = json
tier1.sinks.hbase1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.SimpleHbaseEventSerializer
tier1.sinks.hbase1.channel = channel1

#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.type = hdfs
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.path = /tmp/kafka/%{topic}/%y-%m-%d
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollInterval = 5
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
#tier1.sinks.hdfs1.channel = channel1
```

I have created the Hbase table in a following way:

```
hbase(main):005:0> create 'application_data', 'json'
0 row(s) in 1.2250 seconds
```

But the scan command on this table returns always

```
hbase(main):021:0> scan 'application_data'
ROW                                                  COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                               
0 row(s) in 0.0100 seconds
```

I have put Flume and Hbase Master in DEBUG, but I see no error nor warning. I can see Flume user gets a connection in Hbase and checking the existence of the table. There's no Kerberos auth on HBase. 
Kafka topics do have data, because I have just double-checked  with console consumer and with the hdfs sink.

I was just wondering if anybody can see an error here or point me in right direction. I think I'm not doing anything strange here.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps consider using Kafka Connect instead of Flume. There are several Kafka Sink Connectors for HBase such as http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/hbase.html

Comment: Thank you Hans! I was aware of that connector, but my client prefers Cloudera-only solution. The above should just work, according to the docs.

Comment: I have the similar setup and use Hbase sink in production, but I usually implement [HbaseEventSerializer](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.2.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/hbase/HbaseEventSerializer.html) myself.  And also I specify zookeeper hosts, however, it is optional property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no errors in your flume log make sure all sinks, sources, and channels are initialized. Sometimes you can miss that messages in the log, and in that case no exceptions or errors are reported.

Comment: Thanks gorros, it was the kafka topic that had no data.

Comment: BTW in Cloudera CM ,Flume -> Quick Links ->  All  was quite useful for me.